Table data visible in query editor but blank in table data view
I've been working on a query with lanquage M that takes a table and gives me the column count the problem is in the query Edito it looks fine but when I load and close the query in the table view I don't see that value .
Here's the code:
let
    // Function to count columns in a table
    CountColumnsFunction = (inputTable as table) as number =>
    let
        ColumnCount = Table.ColumnCount(inputTable)
    in
        ColumnCount,

    // Get the table reference directly
    TableReference = Record.Field(#sections[Section1], "REF Credit Limit"),
    ColumnCount = if TableReference <> null then CountColumnsFunction(TableReference) else null,
    
    // Profile the table with only the column count
    ProfileTable = [
        DB_Name = "DB1",
        Table_Name = "REF Credit Limit",
        Column_Count = ColumnCount
    ],
    
    // Convert to table
    TableProfiling = Table.FromRecords({ProfileTable}, type table [
        DB_Name = text,
        Table_Name = text,
        Column_Count = Int64.Type
    ])
in
    TableProfiling

You can see a screenshot of the problem in both links below
That the table showing in Query editor
That's the table showing in the table view after loading the query and in the column Count Column you can seee the value 4 is gone

Why is the Index column not present after it is loaded?

Couple issues with the Code
I am not sure why to define a custom function for a built-in function.
CountColumnsFunction block is redundant as you can replace it with Table.CountColumns() in the code itself
Your main issue is the TableReference.
Since CountColumns is null, that means that the TableReference is returning null when called.
